# Out or out of which is it?

Tags: prepositions, american-english, british-english

Which is correct 
1 Get out the house. Or
2 Get out of the house?
I've heard that the American English standard is the first one and the British English standard is the second one. Is that true? The Oxford dictionary says in a side note that out as a preposition is standard in American English while the prepositional phrase out of is standard in British English while saying out is not standard.

Comment: Americans say *go out the door*, but ***not*** *get out the house.* It is *get out of the house* on both sides of the pond. That's because before you go/get out, you are in the house, but you're not in the door.

Comment: You can *get out the house* if it is a toy house you want to play with. If you want to exit your domicile you *get out of your house* (or *you exit your house*). (American English)

Answer (score 1):

In American English (and [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=went+out+the+door%2Cwent+out+of+the+door%2Cwent+out+the+house%2Cwent+out+of+the+house&year_start=1800&year_end=2009&corpus=18&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwent%20out%20the%20door%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwent%20out%20of%20the%20door%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwent%20out%20of%20the%20house%3B%2Cc0) shows British English is moving towards this usage as well, although they're several decades behind AmE) there is a difference between *out the house* and *out the door*. What *out* without an *of* means is *out through*.

So you can go *out* the door, because you were originally in the house, and you go out of the house through the door. But you can't go *out* the house, because you start in the house.

Comment: It's actually "outa da house" and "out da door," but that's probably too complicated and off-topic.