# Does "towed out the hangar" violate any grammar rules?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

"The plane was towed out of the hangar."

"The plane was towed out the hangar."

I found myself writing that second sentence because it's shorter and seems to flow better. Does it violate any grammar rules? I can't explain my suspicions that well. It trips some grammar alarm in me. The removal of a preposition is something to be wary of I guess.

BTW, it's the narrator saying that in exposition, so I can't pass it off as colloquial speech.

And curiously, how would you diagram both sentences? The first one has two prepositions in a row.

Comment: Lacking the preposition, "towed out" reverts to being a phrasal verb, which in this case is transitive (or anyway reversed in action from *tow out of*: *being towed*), so it causes the entire sentence to fail. Anyone reading it, if they didn't subconsciously "autocorrect" without noticing, would assume (or insist!) it was an error, instead of intentional. Your editor will likely balk (because he, like I, would disagree that it "flows better"). If you want to make it shorter, just drop "of the hanger". If your setting is a airfield anyway, there's not many other places it could be towed out of.

Comment: *Out* is an intransitive preposition, like *away*--it doesn't take an object. You need the additional *of* PP to designate the origin of the towing, just as you need a *to* PP to designate the goal: *The plane was towed out to the runway*.

Comment: @StoneyB Stop being better at this than I am! It's like you study English grammar professionally or something. ;)

Comment: Correction: There is a transitive *out* but it means *out **through**: *He towed the airplane out the door*.

Comment: @DanBron Strictly amateur, I assure you (not to say amateurish). I only know enough to put down clients who think they know more about English than me.

Comment: @DanBron I never said it flows better. I said it *seems* to flow better--key word there. Can you explain things better in an answer? I'm having trouble digesting the compacted logic.

Comment: @DrZ214 Ok, I disagree that it *seems to flow better*. Better? ;) I'm too lazy to put up an answer; the question isn't broad enough to be useful to many people, so doesn't seem worth the effort.

Comment: @StoneyB What does PP mean? I know prepositional phrase and participle phrase and past participle and I think the permutations are about to multiply.

Comment: @DanBron Oy, that's quite a blow. I guess I'll stare at it and ask StoneyB.

Comment: Sorry, techie jargon: preposition phrase. (I belong to the school which calls it a preposition phrase rather than a prepositional phrase because the -al suffix suggests a phrase that acts as a preposition rather than one which is headed by a preposition.)

Comment: @StoneyB Thanks, I belong to no school that I know of, but prefer an adjectival form of a noun when actually using it as an adjective. Never realized there's a distinction between the two ways you mentioned. Anyway, can you post a detailed answer? My mind cannot navigate what Dan Brown posted. I can understand your first comment, though, but "the hangar" doesn't have to be its object. Is it possible to have an understood preposition similar to an understood subject "you" in "Go home." ?

Comment: Would you say "He went out the office." or "He went out *of* the office."; "Come out there!" or "Come out *of* there!"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Out or out of which is it?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/290026/out-or-out-of-which-is-it)

Comment: Isn't this a case of a preposition being dropped in AmE that would normally be included in BrE? Same as _He jumped out the window_ (AmE) vs _He jumped out **of** the window_ (BrE)

Comment: Could "out of" > "from?" How does that flow?

Comment: @BillJ What are AmE and BrE? I know I heard "out the window" before. Hafta think about that one.

Comment: @DrZ214 AmE stands for American English, and BrE stands for British English.

Comment: @Stan It's a fact that in BrE we tend to use the additional preposition "of". For example we say _out **of** the door_ and _out **of** the window_, whereas in AmE they would say _out the door_ and _out the window_.

Answer (score 1):

Your second sentence, even though you could probably figure it out, doesn't technically mean much because "out" simply doesn't have the same meaning as "out of," and you need that second preposition to establish the relationship of "the hangar" to the rest of the sentence. I suggest changing it to "The plane was towed from the hangar" if you want to preserve the rhythm.

Comment: lol this is a simple solution, no clue why it was downvoted. I guess I'll use it since three people already agree my second sentence is wrong.